# MOMC error in xCode 6.2 beta

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode

Everything is fine, when i am trying to compile my application through xCode 6.1, But,while i am trying to compile the same application in xCode 6.2 beta.I am receiving this error

dyld: problem loading iOS simulator dyld
Command /Volumes/Xcode/Xcode-Beta.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/usr/bin/momc failed with exit code 1

I tried this 
[MOMC error with XCode4 and Data Model Compile](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7705206/momc-error-with-xcode4-and-data-model-compile?rq=1), but not yet solved.